# Get div innerHTML onBlur?

Tags: html, reactjs

How can I extract the innerHTML from the onBlur event?

I have previously only used onChange and onClick event handlers. In those cases the event argument (or at least first argument) passed to the callback has been an object from which I have been able to extract event.target.value.

But the onBlur event returns another kind of object:

```
Proxy {[[Handler]], [[Target]], [[IsRevoked]]}
```

How do I extract innerHTML from that?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Subject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }
  onBlur(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>subject</p>
        <p contenteditable="true" name='subject' onBlur={this.onBlur}>{this.props.subject}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data from `contentEditable` you can do `console.log(event.target.textContent)`.

So your program will look like

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class Subject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }
 onBlur(event) {
  console.log(event.target.textContent);
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
     <p>subject</p>
     <p contentEditable="true" name='subject' onBlur={this.onBlur}>{this.props.subject}</p>
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```